# Does ActiveMQ Artemis automatically reload LDAP-based Security Settings?

Tags: openldap, activemq-artemis

I've read about the automatic configuration reload which - [according to the docs](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) - also includes security settings. What I could not figure out yet (and did not see any indications for ) is if Artemis also updates Roles etc. when the LDAP auth is active.

Question is: In an ActiveMQ Artemis deployment where OpenLDAP is used for authentication and authorization do I need to take care about updating the roles etc. myself or is this done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation you cited](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) is related to reloading `broker.xml` when a change is detected. It isn't really applicable to the LDAP authorization data since that data is in LDAP and not in `broker.xml`. However, the [documentation for the LegacyLDAPSecuritySettingsPlugin](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#legacyldapsecuritysettingplugin) is relevant as it discusses the `enableListener` option:

> `enableListener`. Whether or not to enable a listener that will automatically receive updates made in the LDAP server and update the broker's authorization configuration in real-time. The default value is `true`.

Since `enableListener` defaults to `true` then changes made to your LDAP authorization data should automatically be reflected in the broker.

[The listener](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/2.13.0/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/LegacyLDAPSecuritySettingPlugin.java#L569) is an implementation of both [`javax.naming.event.NamespaceChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/event/NamespaceChangeListener.html) and [`javax.naming.event.ObjectChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/event/ObjectChangeListener.html) and is registered using the [`javax.naming.event.EventDirContext#addNamingListener(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, javax.naming.directory.SearchControls, javax.naming.event.NamingListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/event/EventContext.html#addNamingListener-java.lang.String-int-javax.naming.event.NamingListener-) method.

That said, you may run into [ARTEMIS-2671](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2671) which will be resolved in the next release (i.e. 2.12.0). It's also possible that your particular LDAP server doesn't actually support this listener functionality. If that's the case then restarting the broker is your only option to reload the LDAP data. Modifying `broker.xml` won't reload it.

Comment: A quick catch up on this topic: actually my question was about OpenLDAP. Apparently the described listener is based on the persistent queries feature which seems not to be supported by OpenLDAP (OID `2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.3`). @JustinBetram do you know or see any other option to initiate a sync? Although kind of hacky but could it work to _fake-modify_ the `broker.xml` to force a sync?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it did not at the time of writing. If I remember correctly most of the issues were somehow related to OpenLDAP. Unfortunately I cannot remember that I've realized your edit back then - thus I suppose I did also not check properly if it would have helped with my issues. Unfortunately I cannot give any more insights here because we completely moved towards a different MQTT only broker.

Comment: At the time I wasn't aware the OpenLDAP didn't implement the LDAP persistent search functionality. Since then another user actually opened [ARTEMIS-4122](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4122) to get support for this use-case.